# How could I resize the android camera preview dynamically?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview

I am programming a program on Android mobile. I want to resize the camera preview dynamically but always fail. I need the camera preview has size as 800*800.
Please help me!

Comment: What error are you getting when it fails? Could you post your code to preview the camera?

Comment: Thanks, Let me write in below.

Answer (score 0):

My code is :

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    if(camera != null)
    {           
        Camera.Parameters myParameters = camera.getParameters();
        myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, myParameters);
        Log.i("my best camera size parameters", String.valueOf(myBestSize.width)+" "+String.valueOf(myBestSize.height));
        myParameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);
        List<String> flashModes = myParameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashModes.size() > 0 && flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
            myParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

        camera.setParameters(myParameters);         

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.startPreview();
    }   
}
```